# Tag review: bluetooth-le

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I suggest to rename (and synonymize) [bluetooth-le](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-le) with [bluetooth-low-energy](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-low-energy) to be a little more verbatim and descriptive here. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-low-energy) as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest removing [bluetooth-le](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-le) and synonymizing [ble](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ble) with [bluetooth-low-energy](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-low-energy), as of now there are no questions with [ble](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ble) but they will pop up later.

Maybe we can also synonymize [bluetooth-smart](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-smart) with [bluetooth-low-energy](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-low-energy)

Comment: Well, there was one that's just been edited out... but yeah, `ble` and the long one is just fine.

Comment: Just added long form tag to the question http://iot.stackexchange.com/q/416/23.

Answer (score 3):

I think [bluetooth-low-energy](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-low-energy) should be the master tag and all other variations either deleted or made synonyms. I'd prefer the latter, because it's a more permanent solution and I don't see much potential for confusion with other topics on *ble* or *bluetooth-le.*